# Problems with base_64 to jpeg decode in php

Tags: php, html, base64, decode

I have a base_64 (in session) string. I can print jpeg image when I'm doing it in HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAyADIAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAFgAQADASIA AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3 ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3 uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD2Pw8/ mXOst/0/EflGgrcrA8Lc/wBrt66hJ+iqP6Vv03uAUUUUgCiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKK ACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAMU0oh6qp/CnUUARG2gbrDGfqgpjWFmww1pAR6GMVYooApNo2 lvndptoc9cwL/hVDR7WC01vWI7aBIYgYcKihR9zJ4H1rcrI0znXNaP8A01iH/kNaYEPhYD7NqJzn OoT8/wDAsf0rdrC8KD/iW3R9b64P/kQ1u0MAooAwKKQBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAB RRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAVj6Od2q643/AE9qv5RR1sVj6IP9L1lvW+P6RoKa Ai8Ij/iRsfW6uDn1/etW7WD4OJPhyJj/ABTTH/yK1b1DAKKKKQBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUVXu r+0skL3VzFCo5JdwK5rUPiN4esog6XJuSc8RDPT1zTsB1tFeQax8YZzuj0uzVOBiSU5I/CuXk+JP igysx1JlyBgCNQP5UWHY+h6K+eo/id4ojxm/D47NGvP6VYk+K3iSRhtniTjnEYxRYLHvtFfP9v8A E/xGsySNeeYqnJRkADflXqnhnx7pmvxrG8gt7vHMbng/Q0WBo6yijr0opCCiiigAooooAKKKKACi iigArH0E5fVD/wBP8n8lFbFcQ2q65Yi4Oj6QNQD31x5mZNuzDAD+tNAbfhDnwvaNx8xduPd2NblY vhEY8KafznMefzJNbVDAKKKKQBRRRQAUUUUAFFFIzKilmYKo5JJ6UADusaF3ICgZJPavKPFXxVZJ ZbTRAAq5U3LcnPsKT4jePrea1fR9Kn3liVuJUPGP7oPf3ryB5ODTSGkXr7VrzULh57u5kmkc5Jds 1TM5x1qvvzRmmMeXJJpQ5xz0qI8DigGgCYSA9qNw9frURx1HSkJFAyXOOhqZJ3jcMrEEc5FVc8Yq QHigD0Twn8S77Sp4re/ka5siQp3csg9RXtthf22p2cd3aSrLDIMqy18nqTngV6D8MvFTaRrK2FzK fsV0duCeEfsf6U7XJaPeKKAcjIoqBBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABWN4b5srpv717cH/wAisP6Vs1jeGB/x KnP966uD/wCRnpoBfCg2+E9KH/Tsh/StisrwwMeFtKA/59I//QRWrQ9wCiiikAUUUUAFFFZ2uazb aDpM1/dNhIxwvdj2AoAi1zxJpvh+2Mt9cKrY+WMcs34V4r4x+IN54gc28DtBZD+AHBf6/wCFc7r+ uXWuanNe3Lks7cLnhR2ArGYls8j6etUOwryEmmNyKCOtSonmYFBRCEY87TineS23O01v2mn5tJHI 4AonSEQwRYUSMvNTcvk0uc4RzS46n0rbi0Z5AXKnb7CoTpyurkcFO1O5PKzKx6GgDLYqVotoz701 o8GmIYy7euc0qdCDT2Q9D045pVQYJzigAUYp8UjLICDgg8UwnjA6Ck3dKBHvvw98bprdsmm3jBb2 NcKc/wCsA/rXfV8saLqkul6nb3sBxJC4Yf4V9N6XqEWq6Zb3sBykyBh7e1Eu5JcoooqQCiiigAoo ooAKxfCxB0GJh/FJK35yMa2ScAmsbwsp/wCEdsnGOUyffJJprYCx4eXb4b0xfS1i/wDQRWlWfoQ2 +H9NHpax/wDoIrQoe4BRRRSAKKKKACvDPinrs994hfT1kP2a0wAnTLY5Ne5E4BNfMvii6+1+JtRu OSGuHI+maaGjEcBhjvUYQlwACTTypaTAByTXTaNowVledQWODz2olJI0jFyZi2+k3M/zFCF6jjrW taaGVeIZDEnJx/KuvS0RQFCDA9quW9oqcqoFYuo2bqnFGfbaKPsTI3Dtz7Cs6z8J7b5pbht390V2 MceRVhYVxyBSTG7GYLKJUCCNQo7Vzup6cttdPOqHynA3DGcH1ruFgVhnbUc9nHIhVlyDRcWh5SbW D7TLG21h1yPQ1Qe0Z7gxxoSpyelenv4VsnmEuzDDnA6VO2iQCdZhGocDggfhVc9hciZ5BcWs9vgO pI9cVVJZuOtevXXh6CVXwigMMYI4rNg8K21vvDork9PpR7XQXsk9jzNIpHOADStGyD5lI9M16SdC tYSSkQB96oahosU0Z+UKccGhVkN0dNzhoz6HmvavhBrJnsrrSpGyYsSx59D1/X+deNXNs9pKUbjB xmup+HWqnTfGFkxPyTN5L89m/wDr4rdao5pKx9F0UUVBIUUUUAFFFFADZDiJz6A1k+Fv+RY07He3 Q/mK1Lg4tpT6If5Vm+GBjwxpg/6do/8A0EU1sBb0pdmj2SjoIIx/46Kt1XsRjT7YekS/yFWKHuAU UUUgCiiigBkvET/7pr5Xvjm7mycneefXmvqibmCT/dP8q+VboZu5B/tn+dNDRoaHYCe481xkJ0z6 12FvEFbOOntWZosKxWa8YJGTW3bgkg1jUd2ddNWReiQ7enNWo920LnIHamxL8vQVYSP5vSoSKbLE Ua7RxU6p19ajjU8CrKY29aolgsfH9aR0x9KlB468UjMSAcDFAiMLxTDH75p5JBJP4UF1zgHk80WA rbc5JFVpUx2q4ze1VZck9Khloozxgj+lZzx4yp5rXZTiqMy4bNQy0cd4i04OhmUdOT7VgaVN9m1S 1l3EeXMr5HsRXoF3AslvIrDIK1555RgvChx8r4rqovoc1ZdT6rRt0asOhANOqrpr+bpdpITktChz +Aq1Vvc5wooopAFFFFAFfUH2abdP/dhc/oaq6Amzw/p6HqLeMf8AjoqXWG26Jft6W8h/8dNLpQ26 VaD0hQfoKa2YFi3GLaIeiD+VSU2MYjUegFOpMAooooAKKKKAGSjMLj/ZNfLF8nl6jMnTEhH619Un oa+X9cQJr96ingXDgcf7RqkNHTaWAbZByQAK3rdelYejqTZxsfSt+3++BisJLU647F2IccVbjBPT qKqxsgONwqyJVUZzmkkNstqp6U8Ajjiq8d0p4PX0q1E6k5NVYm4AeopeBU+0EZppRc47+tKwXIWH GBUZU+lWSmBjtSEKBk0WuFyqYzmopE46VJJOisRmqbXseTk8D1NS4lJiyRYWs+4GM+tTvqlvlk3j eOozVdp4ZwTG4NRKJSZSl5BBrgtRjVdUkPvk16BIN24VwOq5/tiRT/e4rajuZVtj6M8PuJPDunMO hto//QRWlWdoEDW3h7T4W+8lugP5Vo1rLdnKFFFFIAooooAzfELbPDept6Wsn/oJq1YDbYwD0Rf5 VR8TnHhbVP8Ar1kH/jprRthi2jHoop9AJBwBS0UUgCiiigAooooAK+aPF0P2fxdqcYGALhsfic19 JzTRW8RkmdUQdWY4FeDfEeC3fxe1zbSJJHchWyh/i6H+VNDRc0xNljEOg2g81FqOtLZqyRnMnf2r QiQR2agYyFxWJDpRnunmlG7nOKze51a20K0es3rZMUbsp6tzTn1bVlJZVcKOxU1q3WoWumLsSNTI eQqis3UPEN/bKqSwJEJFyM9cU0+yJa7sSLxRfRPiRe/Jrc0zxXJP8rxYOeuawbG5uNXeTNrHIY1y wCc4rVtoISMIuweq9qUnYqMb7Ha2mpGSMH19atNMQRycVy9g7xyiJmyAODXSKodOanmuDVhxuQgL HOKzrvUPLBOTjr16VbnQKhz+NYF64+bH3R3qXKxSjc5/VNevEuWSMjGfTkVmqNbvDx5mCe/AxWvN vLv5MIJUbmOOg9Se1YX9tTmYKJGGTxz0qk21ohNJPVk/9g6uDu3ZOP7/ADSpdX2mzA3CMuD19a0D qN/p7R/bFzE+Cp6g/jWnLFb6lbhtoOeQcc0OXRoFHqh9tcJdwLKhyGFcjFZvqXjCKzQZMlwE/Xn9 K6jSrY26yR5yoPA7irngDSY5/GN7qU5CpbMRHuPVjx/KrpL3rkVfhPXUUIiqBgAYFOoByMiiqOYK KKKACiiigDI8Uc+GNRHrCR+fFacPES/Ss3xNz4eux6hR+bAVpxfcH0p9AH0UUUgCiiigAooooAxf FFmbrRpGXO6L58DuO9eJ+JIkGqWrr9046fWvoVlDKVYZBGCDXhXjnTV0zXRGownmblHsaa3NYv3W jUjXMQB9KVoTGjEelOhP7pcnNX1RXABFYy3N0cg9l/xMftE6Fl7e3vWnrOk22sxRSRTKk6jbhu4r eNqrfeXIp62EechFGBVJ2B2ZleHNLj0eOZgRNO/BIGAB6ZPvTv7Oma9+0DZEc/MF6MPet+K3RRjg D2FE+xYiFHXvRLXcIu2xkGJVuBsHA6mtq3kPl5PpWaQFzVy3bCVmVuPu5PkIB61kXULyxERYDg9T WjOeD3z1qNQN/tU9R7FGxEUNvLazW7IsgIZwc5yK5j/hEZm1AFZoPJDZD7ucfSu++zRumemaqzaZ DIScfka1vYh2buY3iKO3uLNLZfnKAAbexqHSbdoYBGf4fWtg6cisCFHHc0GIKd1RJtlRSSsiokYV mOMZrG0sFvEF/EWO0EMBnit9iMnFZfhjT31LxVdqmcBsE9gP8iqpakzsmmet6ISdGtS3XZ3q/TIo lhhSJBhUAAFPrU5HqwooooEFFFFAGT4l50OUf3pIh+ci1px8otZfiT/kEqPW5tx/5FStVPuin0Ad RRRSAKKKKACiiigAryz4s2225sroAfMNvTuP/wBdep1yXxD0ptR8NPJGuZLY+YOMnHenHcadmcTb OGgQ9iorUgbgVgaTKZbKI55wBW7B0HrWUtGdcdUaCLu4Gak2YqOFsNz+VWSB1ouDQ1F4zVe4UkZ5 wKtquar6h+7tmI6mkwW5mh90hHoavQ5K8daz4F2jJxnNbVlGvl/MeMUki27FKdTjmoocs238qvXi DkgjFZ6MUuVI9cVD3HuaCZCAGggjmpSuQD696QKOtUiCMqCOetVLhBtINX2HFUrjgelDGkZzcD/G tr4a2WLe+1FuTNKVU+w61hXTeVbyyHsp/lXfeELM2PhexjZSrsnmMD6tzWlLZsyrvSxuUUUVZzBR RRQAUUUUAZPiEZsIB63lv/6MU1qr0FZmujNrbD/p7h/9DFaS9BT6AOooopAFFFFABRRRQAU10WSN kcZVhgj1FOooA8lutMTSNSuLSMfIkhK/Q8ircPAFa3jS1EWow3CjHmrgn3FZUR+QdKmojqpu6LcY G8EjmrqjOKoxE7quRnBFQWyZcKDVDUN0kRxg4q08gUdapyPuPtSBGPdTS7f3UqIR2Ydat2l85QJK Crgc46H6Uk1pFI28oCc1chgUICVHTvVKISkine3c5VBCFGTyzHgcU+2k8/aCBuB5xTrmAE7WUEUs CrFjAxUNDTVjWiwYwKQ4FRRSjHUVK53YouIjc9j0zVG5IxxyferbgcnPWqUvJJpMpCWOlHWLlbUn CH5pCOyg816UqhFCqMADAFcp4PizLdS+gCj/AD+FdZW8dInLVd5BRRRTMgooooAKKKKAMzWRlLNf W6j/AEyf6VpL0FZur/6zTh63Y/8AQHNaQ6U+gC0UUUgCiiigAooooAKKKKAOc8Z23m6VHMBkxSD8 jxXJ23MYr0bULUXmnz25H30IH17V5vDmNijcEHBpS1RvSZfhGDmpmfaN3aqyN8wxxT5WJG0dKzZo QSymWTg8Cmk449aVVCAsazLnUmhkwIHbPQ0irN7GouCAWOKtRyI6/K6kDjrXIy3N/ctxGQvYZoWG +5wCPo3FO7NFST3Z1jvG5wHUt6A1Aw25BHNc19nv0XzANrD3q1b6vcArHcQsT/eFTd9ROnbY1myy 7QSKv275jGeaoQyiRclSv1q1C2Gx2pEE0vC1RkOBVuVuBzVJ+TQFzrvCUZXTJHP8Uhx+Arfqjo9t 9k0qCLGG27m+p5q9XQcknd3CiiigkKKKKACiiigDN1Tm400f9PWf/Ib1ojoKo6iM3Wne05P/AJDe rw9KfQBaKKKQBRRRQAUUUUAFJzn2paOtABXn2sWxtdZnXaQrNuU+xr0GuB8V3WPEYhPQRL/WguD1 KyMOO1P3ZY5qBGyPfFLnI4rJnQP43Dv7VBcQJKuCKb88cnXI9KlQ7x0qblldLcRY54oWeFGwYzk9 6sMhqExDOdtO47j0WNx0ODxUkdrGrA7fzpI06VMTjGKTC7EeMAjFOwAoxUDynNOXJXmle4mOZiRz Uun232zUoIcZBYbvoOtQE4rrfDumi2t/tUg/eyjjPZauC1M5ysjc6CiiitTlCiiigAooooAKKKKA Kd2M3lmPRmb/AMdx/WrYqrcc39t/uuf/AEGrdN7AFFFFIAooooAKKKKACiiigArzbxZGJPEtwA3z +WpHtxXfajqVppVm91eTLFEgJyT19h715hcagNav59XgDfZpJdqFuuAAP8adtGy6fxD7Sfcu08MO CKuBuOKzrqFlbz4RyOoHenQXiyjIP4dxWb1N9jQKqetCfKarrMMjNSk5AqLFJlgc9Kf5YPJqCKXB 57VZMinvTQrjNm3tTZGHalklGM+lVzJubNSxpisORS7gAOfxqN5QBiq5lyePxpIZYaT51A5JIGK9 NUBVAHQCvK7f575G5Ii/ekD/AGea9OsruK+sobqBg0cqBlPsa2gvduc9V62J6KKKoyCiiigAoooo AKKKKAKk/wDyErb/AK5yfzWrdU5v+Qpa/wDXKT+aVcpsAooopAFFFBOOtABRVDUNa03S4zJe3kUK j+83P5Vxup/FrRrVilnFLdN/e+4v60Aeg1la54h0/wAP2TXN7MFA+6g5Zj6AV5Fqnxc1i7DLZxQ2 qHIyBub8zXCX+p3epXLT3c8k0rHlnOaqwHR+J/F934qvC0n7q3jz5UQPQep967vwbZw3XhuCEj5W BOfQ5ryG34A4OfWvWfhzc+bpbRHrHIR+FapaC2ZensZbRzFKOP4T2NYmoWTRMZ4B8wGSvrXpstrF eQbJFB9D6VzGo6VJbMdwJXswrCUbbHRCd9GchDd7j1ww6rV2K9Vlx0PbNRXulEyGSMlWrPy0TYmQ gjHNRcuxsi5CtjOc1J9tUZ54rGDIeQSPxqXMYHUkeuakDRN2hzh6ia+jT+LP0qgWRW4GaaqNK2FX A9RRoMsm6e4YBQQKthNqc/WpLDTJZX2xxlj7V0ttokVuoe4AdxyF7CmoOWwnNRMWztTBYzzyKQ0q lVHoO9UfAfjWLTj/AGNqLbYfMIhlJ+7k/dPtW1rcwt9PuJjxsQkV4tMxEhbnk108qSscspczufU6 sGUMpBBGQR3pa8V8GfEmXShHYapulsxwsnVox/UV69p+q2Oq26z2VzHMjDPynkfUVm1YC5RRRSAK KKKACiiigClN/wAhi1H/AExk/wDQkq7VGX/kNW//AFwf/wBCWr1N7IDLvvEWkabn7XqEEZHUFwT+ Vcvf/FbQ7bctss1yw6FVwP1rw5nd2LMzN6k0wjceOvSqUQPTL/4vajP8tjZw24P8Tnea5m/8ceIb /IfUZVU5yqfKP0rnETGQfSkcsFwAOnWqUUFyS5vJpm3SSu7tySzE5qqzZOaeFIOSPrmmNwB9KAGF j06UwElsUH5yFUEk1dtoNnzMBn0NCVwvYljX5CT97Fd/8NptlxcQHuA1cGFyAwGfcV2PgGXbrgU5 +eMj29a0SIPZoPuCpZIklQq6gg9jUFuflFWh0rOW5RzmoaHtDPDyvda5u4sEZiGTH4V6M3IrE1TT ll/eR4D/AM6zlC+qNY1O5wUukr/CxFQjTG6FuK6GWMxuVYYI9qs2elzXbDClU/vGsuVt6G/MkjnY NJ3OFALMemK6bS/C3SS5+Veyd66Kx0uCzUFVy/dj1q6eK0jTS3MZVG9irHbQ20eyJFUD0FVrk4Wr krVm3b5U1ujI4Txxf+XYiBSQ0p/SvNJEZuQucDJI7D3rqvF10LnWmQHKRjZ+PeubM7xxypGxAddr j1HB/oKOhPUofdPzZ+gqzaapd6fKJLOeSE5zlWxVYgk8ikPLdTj61Iz0DR/ivrFlsS9RLuPpkja2 PrXf6V8TPD+pBVlna0lP8Mw4z9elfP5XkYxzQMg0mkB9WwXUF1GJLeaOVD0KMCKlr5esdY1DS5A9 neTQn0ViAa7LTfi1rNoAt7FFdJxyRtP6UnELnt9FcFpnxY0G82rdCW0c/wB5dy/mK7Cy1bT9RjD2 d5DMCMjY4J/Kp5WO42TnXIR6W7/+hLV+s6Q/8T+L2tm/9CFaND2QHyuykAL+lMGefTpViQZPIyvY 0jJxxkg9citrE3I9hZegyRUTKScqcd/rVnkHPTj04FMbhQB+OKdgIUI4UqQSaZLuZhGoIPr7VKIy xOckdh6VYjiwdxU9OOKVrhchgtgrAqQzdfpUrHAOfTP1qTGACnBBpHUElhjJ9Kq1hXGQdscDvit3 wzdfZdbtpCSF34Yn8qwVDBuBx3q/ayeVNHIOArA00B9A2z5Aq7uAFZGmzCazilHRkDZ/CrMpZsEk hB29ahrUowPEXxB0nQmaDf8AaLoHBjj/AIfqe1efap8TdVviRa7LZM8beT+tdP438Cx6vHJqWnqF usZdB/Hj0968cKPDMY3BBU4INTsxnW2fxG1S2lBu4obtf9oYP5ivTfC3j3SdcCwbvs1z08tzgH6G vAJhhutJFI8bh42IYHgg0rh0PrAMCOKa54rhPh3r2q6jpJGpROYoyFjuG/i9j6/Wu0kbiq5REUj5 rJ1Ob7NaXE7fdjjL/kK02Hy1znjOf7N4aumHWTCfmaoDyOeWSSaSWRsl2LH61Vnj3fMM/h0p8rDn npUO7OR17nHegkgI3nZxuqMjAIPWrUkQYcHGentUMsZJwfvY/OlYYzbhf14NJtJ56cZpACxwSMin ZG3g5agBq4J2nAx/KnEZBweKTDkrwPbFO+8euD6ikBFtII4xUsF1cWsnmQTPGw6MjEEUu0KpP4A0 zBPUflSsO5678K9a1DV768W/uXn8iFFjL8kAk55/CvU68d+DQA1HUx/0yj/ma9iqZDPlzBHU8t3p Rk85HHXingKB744xQRyMda2IGSkDbUIQuwBG0enpU+7EnzEbW9ak2lQWK/e6E0bgQQqqNzkipQTu OAOnSnKv7zldwFPVS24qmR6jtTERbcoemT3ppI2hR0P5VMq/IWJIX+H3pjDupwe/FAEC8yH3GeKu AjGTjAFVQv7w5wMHqKsYPlZB+Ue1CGe2eEp/tXh2zcjBCY/EcVusAQRXIfDu4EugGPvHIR/WuwPF S9xoZBggqa8E+IAtk8ZXiWyoqKVBC9N2OfxzXqvjDxEPDmkTyo2LiUFIR/tHv+HWvA5JWuZ2llYs 7sSzE8k1EnqUhJjlx0rsvAfgt/EF19ougyWUR+Y/3z6CuO+RQCRmvafhj4ht77SRpm1I7i3HQDG9 fX60LcGdnHbw2sCWtvGscKDaFA4AqQcHYfwJ/lUu0ZOKaQKoQw85FcH8SbrZa2lqpGXcuR7Dj+td +V3jg814/wCPro3fiR4e0Cqn49T/ADoA5G5wScAj14qvGxPoPapJuTgZzxUPGMlTnOOtPqImRgUH bHU0MoKbjgk1FuYYXAqdMuQEB5HrQIqPE4AJY4xxj+tNVQjfXniru0nIYDB71E8ZQ5ByPWlYdxrL 0weetIMFenIpyjfxk80HIyAaBDSh+vpSlSRTlAwPTtUp4I9KdgPRPg6uL/VCf+eUf82r1+vJPhB/ x/6t15SL+bV63WU9ykfMbA9c8+lCdSB1UdDStnHHGB0PFRgYbjKjrmtyRJyGcDBHrz1qVJC8JDFs jpnvTAo2heS3qKlOMBinIAHHFJIBitg7/m49qmywUAHC9do/nUTBskjIHpnrUnVm5wcDOe1MQnlt t2sCxxxnigoAMHGSO46UHqB82AKUK4BIBK56mgZGQwBB7+nenR5EZAGVH50wk4JOGI6gUsWOBjr1 5piPQ/hnd5kvbbJHCuB+ld1q2p2+k6dNe3LhYolySe/oK8t8BXAtvEqxg8SoV6+2aT4sa5Lvg0dW wv8Arn569lH8/wBKieiuVE4zxN4luvEeptczHbGOI485CCshW4yKgB4qdAPLIHWskWxksmGwK2fD WrTaRqcN5CxBjbOPUdxWEykNzVq3UquRTT1B7H0/p1/DqVhDdwNlJVDD/CrA75rzr4V6t5tjcabI 3zxHegJ7HrXog+9WlrElOe4MDMcgAc14fqd41/qt7eNnMkhYYPavW/Ftx9k0W6lBwfLKj6nivGHB WPpnj07UITKMuHcqenY05QAm/GB0xUZ+YklefanEHtk4oEO2qRhRz1J9aZEWhmV0OCpzTmP7sYzn HQ0kYBw35/1oA0cxXQ8wAJJ3Ung/SoZIykbZGR2yetNBUAFTjB4NJIzNkM2VBwPSmBWkdlfI+73G OtSsN33QOnORVSRi0hAPAPXFXFLNHkdDxSQEas3HA59qkU7o8DsO9NwwY9vxpEOSQSAM9aAPTfhC o+36sV/uRc/i1es15R8Ilxfaueo2RDI/4HXq9ZT3KR84voms9P7IvB64T6/4VXfTtQQgSaZd8H/n ka+gl8OaQn3LGNP93Ip39haft2+U2308xsfzqvaBZHz59kvUc7tOu1AOMGFuD6UxzMpwba5APH+q P+Ht+lfQ39g6dnPktn18xv8AGmv4d01/vQuf+2jf40e0Cx87qzIAvkzBskcxnPH4UJMqsUcMM/7B r6Fbw1pbEFoXOPWVv8aY/hXSJGBaBye2ZW/xo9oFj5/+0Q4JYhQBgg560efCFUiVQB2zg179/wAI lpGCPIfnP/LVu/XvTB4N0UHIt3DeokbP86ftBcp4A80Lf8tEAPqc96fHJEGyJEPrlule+HwdoxJJ tiSeTlic1GfA+hMMGzTGc4wOtHtA5TxrRr6Kx1yyuPMX5ZF3c9iaw/GOonVfFN9cBtyeYUQ5yNq8 DH5V76fAWg8EWUWR0ygqI/D3w+xJNhDk8n92KUpKQ1ofNYXjpU0Y4zX0Yfhz4fIP+gQcjH3Kib4a eHjn/QIufQEf1qdB3PngR5JPapV4H417+fhj4e7WMfT1b/GoW+FmgEf8emMDtK/+NPQDy/wFqf8A Zvim2LPhJj5TZ9D0/XFe9RnOTXJD4V6KknmRxyIwOQVmYYPtzWkvhB42zHqN+vsLt/6mq5tBGD8S 7oR6XBb7gGlkzgnHAGf8K8wuHIh2k/LjPFewah8O4tT2m6v76UpnbuuM4z9RVBvhPYsoH2q8H/bR T/7LTUkJo8g2ZzxzjPFSxqTHgDGRzg16ofhFaAHbfXgz/tIf/ZajPwiQfc1G5B7ZVDRzILHlrKCW z17ikXO4AcD0r08/COQg/wDE0lzkHmJf8ahPwkvVA26qCf8Aatwf/ZqfMhWPPy3mKF6leOlMUFV2 YyWHUGvQD8J9SXO3Uoj/ANsCP/ZqjHwp1dSx+3W7E9zG3+NHMgseeSJtbHAOakU4BByK7uT4U6yR xdWpOf7jVEfhZrqni4tG+u8f+y0XCxxTc9evriosBX9R3ruT8MfEABG6yPHTe/8A8TUJ+GfiFTkL Zn281v8A4mgDo/hEFEOpycDLRrk98Bj/AFr0/ev94fnXl3h74WCW2kk1qeaKcv8AItrNgbcd+Ouc 1s/8Ks0fnF/qY+k4/wAKzlZspHdUUUVmMKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACkJApaKACiiigAooooAKKK RRtGMdyaAFooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA//9kAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==" />
```

But when I'm want to display it in php it's don't working. For example http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html decoding it to image.
I've tried this methods

`

```
$data = base64_decode($query);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

or

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$query.'" />';
```

or

```
$imagedata=base64_decode($query);
$length = strlen($imagedata);
header('Last-Modified: '.date('r'));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$length);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
print($imagedata);
```

And no one of them is working correctly.

**Many thanks in advance for any ideas.**

Answer (score 0):

The variable $query is not correct, do you get $query from $_POST or $_GET, the base_64 data may has some "=" in the end, when the data send to server, the "=" will be encoded.

Comment: I'm getting $query from Session and in the end there are 'AA=='

Comment: Try to set $query to the original base_64 string, if it works, there may be some other question in data transfer. Do you check if the blank charset has been encoded?

Comment: Yes, i check it. in online decoders it's decoding. And i decode many base_64 strings in other projects- but now , i don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Can you paste the $query data here. And how do you get it from $_SESSION.